# Custom OpenERP module doesn't work as intended

Tags: python, inheritance, python-2.7, overriding, odoo

I am modifying the Purchase module to add a new field in purchase order lines. I have successfully added the code to create model and view the custom field. But unable to add the custom field to total amount of the P.O. line.

```
class customPo(osv.osv):

    _inherit="purchase.order"
    #_name = 'customPo'

    def _amount_all(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
        res = {}
        cur_obj=self.pool.get('res.currency')
        for order in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            res[order.id] = {
                'amount_untaxed': 0.0,
                'amount_tax': 0.0,
                'amount_total': 0.0,
            }
            val = val1 = 0.0
            cur = order.pricelist_id.currency_id
            for line in order.order_line:
               # val1 += line.price_subtotal
               val1 = val1 + line.data + line.price_subtotal
               for c in self.pool.get('account.tax').compute_all(cr, uid, line.taxes_id, line.price_unit, line.product_qty, line.product_id, order.partner_id)['taxes']:
                    val += c.get('amount', 0.0)
            res[order.id]['amount_tax']=cur_obj.round(cr, uid, cur, 42.0)
            res[order.id]['amount_untaxed']=cur_obj.round(cr, uid, cur, val1)
            res[order.id]['amount_total']=res[order.id]['amount_untaxed'] + res[order.id]['amount_tax']
        return res

        _columns = {
            'order_line': fields.one2many('purchase.order.line', 'order_id', 'Order Lines', states={'approved':[('readonly',True)],'done':[('readonly',True)]}),
            'amount_untaxed': fields.function(_amount_all, digits_compute= dp.get_precision('Account'), string='Untaxed Amount',
                store={
                    'purchase.order.line': (_get_order, None, 10),
                }, multi="sums", help="The amount without tax", track_visibility='always'),
            'amount_tax': fields.function(_amount_all, digits_compute= dp.get_precision('Account'), string='Taxes',
                store={
                    'purchase.order.line': (_get_order, None, 10),
                }, multi="sums", help="The tax amount"),
            'amount_total': fields.function(_amount_all, digits_compute= dp.get_precision('Account'), string='Total',
                store={
                    'purchase.order.line': (_get_order, None, 10),
                }, multi="sums",help="The total amount"),
        }
customPo()

class customPol(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'purchase.order.line'
    # _name = 'something.notpurchase'
    _columns = {
        'data': fields.float('Unit Price', required=True, digits_compute= dp.get_precision('Product Price')),
    }

customPol()
```

I have kept the tax static as 42 so, I can know when the overridden method is called but it never happens.

My view file is the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
        <record id="custom_purchse_wa" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Custom Field New</field>
            <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page/field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='price_unit']" position="after">
                <field name="data" string="Custom field"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
</data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: can you see the field in the view? if yes, can you specify any float variable for the field data? please check the database whether this data is entered in the database

Comment: > can see the field in view, can add data to it, data copies to db, can add that data to my total by modifying purchase.py (inbuilt module) But my challange (standard procedure) is to do the same without modifying original purchasy.py

Comment: @AshokKumarSahoo  Can you succeed to add this value in purchase order and every calculaton work fine like tax, total amount if yes can you please add your code here

Comment: I am not developing openerp anymore, I am working on web applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to override

```
 _amount_line
```

function in purchase.order.line class
so you'll able to do calculation on amount